# SQLite query with buildString method instead of params String array

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've previously tried this statement:

```
public Cursor searchForSchools(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    String myQuery = "SELECT skola._id, skola.naziv, skola.privatna, skola.adresa, opstina.naziv, skola.broj_ucenika, skola.telefon, skola.web, oblast.naziv " +
                    "FROM skola JOIN opstina ON skola.id_opstina = opstina._id " +
                    "JOIN profil ON skola.id_tip = profil._id " +
                    "JOIN oblast_m ON profil._id = oblast_m.id_profil " +
                    "JOIN oblast ON oblast_m.id_oblast = oblast._id ";
    return database.rawQuery(myQuery + "WHERE skola.naziv LIKE \"%?%\" AND opstina.naziv = ? AND skola.broj_ucenika ? AND skola.oblasti LIKE \"%?%\" AND skola.privatna ?", args);
```

But that didn't work, due to a SQL syntax error.

So now, I'm trying to build the second part of the clause in the following method:

```
public Cursor searchForSchools(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    String myQuery = "SELECT skola._id, skola.naziv, skola.privatna, skola.adresa, opstina.naziv, skola.broj_ucenika, skola.telefon, skola.web, oblast.naziv " +
                    "FROM skola JOIN opstina ON skola.id_opstina = opstina._id " +
                    "JOIN profil ON skola.id_tip = profil._id " +
                    "JOIN oblast_m ON profil._id = oblast_m.id_profil " +
                    "JOIN oblast ON oblast_m.id_oblast = oblast._id ";
    return database.rawQuery(myQuery + buildQueryString(args), null);
}

private String buildQueryString(String[] args) {
    String buildString="WHERE";
    if(args[0]!="*")
        buildString += " skola.naziv LIKE %\"" + args[0] + "\" AND";
    if(args[1]!="*")
        buildString += " opstina.naziv = \"" + args[1] + "\" AND";
    if(args[2]!="*")
        buildString += " skola.broj_ucenika " + args[2] + "\" AND";
    if(args[3]!="*")
        buildString += " oblast.naziv LIKE %\"" + args[3] + "\" AND";
    buildString += " skola.privatna " + args[4];
    return buildString;
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the args array contains '*' (asterisk sign) which indicates that the query isn't relevant to that column (i.e. any value is acceptable) however in the first method of calling that results in a clause like " WHERE opstina.naziv = '*' " which returns an error...

So let me explain my goal - I'd like to create a dynamic SQL statement that can handle all the cases from returning all data (when args[]={'*','*','*','*','*'}) to the most complex case when each of the args strings has value different from "*". Thanks in advance...

Comment: use `args[] = {filter1, hasfilter1, filter2, hasfilter2, ....}` and query string like `"(filter1 LIKE ? OR 0 = ?) AND (filter2 = ? OR 0 = ?) AND ..."` ... (hasfilterN has 0 or 1 value) if you put 0 to hasfilterN then this filter is dissabled

Comment: Well thought safety-net, thanks for the advice :D